# Simple scrollable list in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started playing with web-app development, ASP.NET Core MVC in particular.

I want to make a simple list, where every item is just a string, and it has one of two possible icons assigned, like on the screenshot.

I tried researching this by myself, but there seem to be so many ways to make different lists, that I don't know what to choose and what is appropriate for the purpose. I'd appreciate some keywords or examples.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you start with a simple `<ul></ul>` unordered list. Create as many `<li></li>` tags as you like and then begin to sprinkle some css over it. When you hit a **concrete** problem, that is related to code, you can edit your quetion accordingly.

Comment: @Marco The items on that list are to be taken from a database, so the size would be dynamic. Is it doable with ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic example:

**RowItem.cs**:

```cs
public class RowItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**:

```cs
public HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // retrieve items from your db
        List<RowItem> items = _service.GetItems();

        return View(items);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**:

```
@model List<RowItem>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @if (item.IsSuccess)
            {
                <i class="arrow-up"></i> @item.Description
            }
            else
            {
                <i class="arrow-down></i> @item.Description
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Of course you need to add the appropriate styles and icons to achieve the look you desire.